# Custom ASP.NET MVC 'RenderTable' helper, how to add some extra functionality?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

so I have a custom html helper I'm making and it renders a table from an `IList` that's passed in. It works fine, but its rather basic. I'd like to have the ability to assign column names that are not inferred from the property name. For example, right now I pass in a property called **Number**, but I'd like to use **№**.

I think I've seen this done through decorations, and I can only assume it uses reflection to get the value out, but I'm not quite sure how to pull it off, yet...

Another thing, I'd like to apply the ability to manipulate the attributes of a cell. For example the **№** cell should have a `colspan` of **x**, or any other cell could have a `class` applied to it. I'm thinking that could also fall under a decoration of some kind.

Lastly, I want to have some cells contain links, but quite frankly, I have no idea how to pull it off, short of sending a complete html string as the property value to render.

So, I'm posting my current version of the code here with the hope that someone better than me (that would be you, **;)**) could give me some pointers on how to accomplish what I've written above.

**UPDATE**

Small update, the IList being passed in right now is an anonymous type, so I'm not sure how that plays with decorations...

```
public static class ApplicationExtensions {
    public static void RenderTable(
        this HtmlHelper HtmlHelper,
        IList Items) {
        RenderTable(HtmlHelper, string.Empty, Items, null, false);
    }

    public static void RenderTable(
        this HtmlHelper HtmlHelper,
        IList Items,
        object Attributes) {
        RenderTable(HtmlHelper, string.Empty, Items, Attributes, false);
    }

    public static void RenderTable(
        this HtmlHelper HtmlHelper,
        IList Items,
        IDictionary<string, object> Attributes) {
        RenderTable(HtmlHelper, string.Empty, Items, Attributes, false);
    }

    public static void RenderTable(
        this HtmlHelper HtmlHelper,
        IList Items,
        object Attributes,
        bool RenderTFoot) {
        RenderTable(HtmlHelper, string.Empty, Items, Attributes.ToDictionary(), RenderTFoot);
    }

    public static void RenderTable(
        this HtmlHelper HtmlHelper,
        IList Items,
        IDictionary<string, object> Attributes,
        bool RenderTFoot) {
        RenderTable(HtmlHelper, string.Empty, Items, Attributes, RenderTFoot);
    }

    public static void RenderTable(
        this HtmlHelper HtmlHelper,
        string Caption,
        IList Items,
        object Attributes,
        bool RenderTFoot) {
        RenderTable(HtmlHelper, Caption, Items, Attributes.ToDictionary(), RenderTFoot);
    }

    public static void RenderTable(
        this HtmlHelper HtmlHelper,
        string Caption,
        IList Items,
        IDictionary<string, object> Attributes,
        bool RenderTFoot) {
        if ((Items != null) && (Items.Count > 0)) {
            StringBuilder TableBuilder = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Caption) ? new StringBuilder() : new StringBuilder().AppendFormat("<caption>{0}</caption>", Caption));

            THead(TableBuilder, Items[0].GetType());
            TBody(TableBuilder, Items);

            if (RenderTFoot) {
                TFoot(TableBuilder, Items[0].GetPropertyCount());
            };

            TagBuilder TagBuilder = new TagBuilder("table");

            TagBuilder.MergeAttributes(Attributes);
            TagBuilder.InnerHtml = TableBuilder.ToString();

            HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(TagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        };
    }

    private static void THead(
        StringBuilder TableBuilder,
        Type Item) {
        TableBuilder.Append("<thead><tr>");

        foreach (var Property in Item.GetProperties()) {
            TableBuilder.AppendFormat("<th>{0}</th>", Property.Name);
        };

        TableBuilder.Append("</tr></thead>");
    }

    private static void TBody(
        StringBuilder TableBuilder,
        IList Items) {
        TableBuilder.Append("<tbody>");

        foreach (var Item in Items) {
            PropertyInfo[] Properties = Item.GetType().GetProperties();

            TableBuilder.Append("<tr>");

            foreach (PropertyInfo Property in Properties) {
                TableBuilder.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", Property.GetValue(Item, null));
            };

            TableBuilder.Append("</tr>");
        };

        TableBuilder.Append("</tbody>");
    }

    private static void TFoot(
        StringBuilder TableBuilder,
        int Columns) {
        TableBuilder.AppendFormat("<tfoot><tr><td colspan=\"{0}\"><input type=\"button\" value=\"&#9664;\" /><input type=\"button\" value=\"&#9654;\" /></td></tr></tfoot>", Columns);
    }

    private static int GetPropertyCount(
        this object Item) {
        return Item.GetType().GetProperties().Count();
    }

    private static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(
        this object Object) {
        return Object.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(
            k =>
                (k.Name),
            v =>
                (v.GetValue(Object, null)));
    }
}
```

And it's used like so:

```
<% Html.RenderTable(Model) // lowest overload... %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [Html.Grid](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=618) from [ASP.NET MVC 3 RC2](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=618). It should be much easier than writing your own helper.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, but it requires MVC 3. I'm working against MVC 2 and I don't plan on messing with MVC 3 until it's fully released. Also, it seems to be trying to take care of a lot of the Ajax stuff, which I don't like because it's already limiting the *code design* I would otherwise implement. I guess, I want mine to just be a generic render-er which I can "Ajaxify" as I wish. And lastly, I've never built an HtmlHelper before so I see this as a nice learning experience.

Comment: @Alex: MVC 3 also features a new concept for HTML helpers, namely declarative helpers. It's much less cumbersome and more maintainable than code-based helpers as available in previous versions. While the "old" style of writing helpers remains the only choice for some scenarios, I have switched to declarative helpers for most of the other stuff.

Comment: Hmm (again), how does that deal with code reuse, short of copying and pasting the helper where you need it? I mean, it looks like you're generating an on page helper as needed which is fine, but then wouldn't you be re-generating the exact same helper on each view you want to use it at? Wouldn't that open the door for consistency problems if one happens to be different somehow?

Comment: @Alex: There are workarounds for that. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2010/10/27/turn-your-razor-helpers-into-reusable-libraries.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: @Adrian, I see, well, that answers my questions, but I still want to finish my HtmlHelper because I'm still on MVC 2...

Answer (score 0):

" so I'm not sure how that plays with decorations..."

It doesn't.  You won't be able to get metadata off of an anon.